# Too Many Arguments for OR function

Tags: excel, function

Hi I am trying to write a quick formula to adjust rate of pay dependent of the date of service.

Here's the formula I've got:

```
=IF(AND(Table1[@User]="Person's name")*(OR(Table1[@Date]>=DATEVALUE("2021-01-01"),Table1[@Date]<=DATEVALUE("2022-05-31"))),"300"*(OR(Table1[@Date]>=DATEVALUE("2022-06-01"),Table1[@Date]<=DATEVALUE("2023-05-31"))), "310"*(OR(Table1[@Date]>=DATEVALUE("2023-06-01"),Table1[@Date]<=DATEVALUE("2025-05-31"))), "320")
```

It works fine with just the first two date ranges, but states there are "too many arguments for this function" when I add the third. Is this a limit with the OR function? If so, what else should I use to allow for multiple date range parameters?

Thanks!

I've modified the date ranges on the third OR function. I've attempted to use TODAY() as well, but the no effect.

Comment: Check the number of arguments you've entered for `IF`. Side note: why do you have numbers in quotes? `"300"`, `"310"`, `"320"`?

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to have a lookup table instead of "hiding" the conditions within the formula

Comment: Your IF() formula have 4 items in it.. It should be just 3 . | I mean it should be `IF(<condition>,<doIftrue>, <doIfFalse>)` .. But your formula is `IF( AND(Table1[@User..    ,"300"*(OR(Table1..    , "310"*(OR(Table1..    , "320")`